# Is it possible to change ModelStateError on a specific object in list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a httpPost where i want to loop through a list of cars. The cars has some properties that has been validated, and a bool on the object that is set to true if a car is `deleted`.

I now want to clear the `modelState` on the cars that has a `bool` that is deleted. I'm looking for something like:

```
foreach (var c in cars ) { 
   if(c.IsDeleted) {
      // delete all the errors for this specific car
      ...
   }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get a list without cars which `IsDeleted` is true,and then use `TryValidateModel` to check the new list,so that you will get a ModelState without errors of cars which `IsDeleted` is true,and you don't need to foreach the list and delete the errors about it one by one.Here is a demo:

Models:

```
public class Cars
    {
        public List<Car> CarList { get; set; }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        [Required]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

Code:

```
public IActionResult Index(Cars cars)
        {
            
            List<Car> list = cars.CarList.Where(c => c.IsDeleted != true).ToList();
            Cars newCars = new Cars { CarList = list };
            ModelState.Clear();
            TryValidateModel(newCars);
            //after `TryValidateModel` you will get a ModelState without errors of cars which `IsDeleted` is true
           
            return View();
        }
```